# Picasso and GestureImageView conflict

Tags: android, picasso

I'm using both Picasso and GestureImageView in my project. However, when I get image from URL and try to put it into a GestureImageView, image is getting low alpha at the beginning. When I tap on the image, it comes normal. I couldn't find the reason of this conflict. Is there a solution or an alternative?

My code below:

```
view = (GestureImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.downstairs_image);

Picasso
    .with(rootView.getContext())
    .load("http://dev.arkenus.com/ikz2014/img/blueprint/" + blueprints.getBlueprint())
    .into(view);
```

Comment: just a guess: `.noFade` in the picasso call. The fade animation might be conflicting with some custom animation drawing that the `GestureImageView` does.

Comment: You should write it as answer and I'll tick it :) It works, thank you so much.

Comment: image not loaded while using picasso and gestureImageView.. i use same process..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a guess:

include `.noFade()` in the Picasso call.

The fade animation might be conflicting with some custom animation drawing that the GestureImageView does